# Problema con sumar rango de valores: foreach con array_sum en php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando calcular la suma de todos los números comprendidos entre 1 y 100. Para ello, he creado un foreach con un rango de 1 a 100, y he visto que se puede sumar array_sum, pero me pone el siguiente código de error:

> array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, int given in "" on line 3

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
foreach (range(0, 100) as $numeros) {
  echo array_sum($numeros);
}
?>
```

Por qué no los puede sumar?

Comment: y que alternativas hay?

Comment: ok, pero como puedo "separar" los numeros generados por el foreach? si creo una variable con valor 0 y sumo el foreach simplemente me mostrara los numeros del 1 al 100 y no los sumara creo..

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! No sabía ni que eran los arrays, ahora sí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución:

```
<?php
$contador= array();
foreach (range(0, 100) as $numeros) {
  array_push($contador,"$numeros");
}
$total= array_sum($contador);
echo $total;
?>
```

No sabía muy bien el tema de los array, he investigado un poco y era más sencillo.

Se suben los numeros a un array en una variable y se suman, esta vez si permitiendolos ya que es un array, perdon por la redundancia.

Comment: Solo como nota el foreach y el contador es innecesario, range ya retorna un array, puedes hacer directamente `array_sum(range(0, 100))`